# Doing computation on folders

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a main directory and 9 subfolders within. I have to first read the path and in each folder excluding specific files and plotting the result with the legend of the name of the folder. The problem is that I can see the files which I need to do computations but then it does not work anything. The code that I wrote is below:

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde

mean_curv = []
FILES=[]
for r, d, f in os.walk(r'C:\Users\Hasan\Desktop\output\new our scenario\beta 15\test'):
    for dirs in d:
        CASES = [f for f in sorted(files) if f.startswith('config')]
        maxnum = np.max([int(os.path.splitext(f)[0].split('_')[1]) for f in CASES])

        CASES = ['configuration_%d.out' % i for i in range(maxnum)]
        FILES.append(CASES)
        for i, d in enumerate(FILES): 
            a = np.loadtxt(d).T 
            num = os.path.splitext(d)[0] 
            local_curv = np.abs(a[4])
        mean_curv.append(np.mean(local_curv))
Time = np.arange(0,len(mean_curv))
plt.plot(Time,mean_curv)
```

The error that I have gotten is below:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-4e1e3e29813a> in <module>
      1 for i, d in enumerate(RIVERS):
----> 2     a = np.loadtxt(d).T
      3     num = os.path.splitext(d)[0]
      4     local_curv = np.abs(a[4])
      5     mean_curv.append(np.mean(local_curv))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin, encoding, max_rows)
   1157         # converting the data
   1158         X = None
-> 1159         for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
   1160             if X is None:
   1161                 X = np.array(x, dtype)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in read_data(chunk_size)
   1085 
   1086             # Convert each value according to its column and store
-> 1087             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
   1088 
   1089             # Then pack it according to the dtype's nesting

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1085 
   1086             # Convert each value according to its column and store
-> 1087             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
   1088 
   1089             # Then pack it according to the dtype's nesting

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in floatconv(x)
    792         if '0x' in x:
    793             return float.fromhex(x)
--> 794         return float(x)
    795 
    796     typ = dtype.type

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'configuration_0.out'
```

Comment: what is `RIVERS`? Also you use same variable `d` in two nested loops as loop variable. It is not recommended to do that. Is this something you intended to do?

Comment: @Ehsan I have edited the notation.

Comment: Thank you. Please note the use of variable `d` in both loops. Not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: @Ehsan I got your point but no it was not the error.

Comment: Do you have a sample data that you can provide to reproduce the error?

Comment: @Ehsan I added more information about the error that I have gotten

Comment: Thank you for adding more info. Do you have headers in your `'configuration_0.out'` file? what is the content of it? try `np.genfromtxt(d)` instead and see if you see nans.

Comment: @Ehsan I have no header, each file has columns separated with spaces and once I tried to use in this code I got the error, when I used the code in each folder, it works but when I used to do the same work on different folder it was not able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring the path to the files, instead of:

```
a = np.loadtxt(d).T
```

you should use:

```
a = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(r, d)).T
```

Comment: In my code there are 2 different `d` that work differently. One of them is working for finding directory, another one is just for enumerating. Your answer points out which `d`?

Comment: @Mir.Emad the same you tried to use to open the file. just prepend it with the path, as shown in my answer.